# YVR Long Connection: Go to the city

Tags: transit, layovers, connecting-flights, yvr

I'll be flying soon SYD-YVR-MEX and have long layovers in Vancouver in both flights (6ish hours and 10ish hours for the return flight). I'm wondering if, given that it's an international to international connection, I'm allowed or not to go outside of the airport (I'm thinking on just waiting at the airport for the 6h connection and try sleep a bit after a long trans-pacific flight, but would like to go to the city on my way back to Sydney). I'm flying Air Canada if that makes any difference. Any help or pointers will be appreciated. Worst case I'll have to wait in the international zone for a some hours (which is good, considering that it's gonna be the first travel after a long time).
Cheers!

EDIT: Mexican Passport (So I have to get eTA), fully vaccinated.

Comment: In normal times (I.e. pre-Covid) this could range from extremely easy if you don’t need a visa to quite difficult if you need one (mostly depends on your nationality). Nowadays it’s quite a bit more complicated for everybody (and rules change extremely often).

Comment: Yeah the vaccination status is important. You cannot leave the airport if you are not vaccinated.

Answer (score 9):

> I'm allowed or not to go outside of the airport

Generally that's allowed.

However, there are few points to consider

- You will be entering Canada. Make sure you have all required documents and visas to enter Canada
- You need to meet all Covid requirements and follow all Covid regulations and registration processes for entering Canada from your country of departure.
- You need to meet all Covid requirements and follow all Covid regulations set out by your destination country for arrival from Canada and Australia.
- Covid rules change often and in unpredictable ways

Depending on what time you arrive, you may have to clear Canadian customs anyway. See https://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/passenger-guides?route=INTERNATIONAL%7CINTERNATIONAL&airline=19

Comment: It's possible they'll ask you to pay the AIF fee ($25 CAD per passenger) if you leave the transit area. In the past they did.